# Amazon EC2 Autoscaling tools does not show particular autoscale group unless explicitly mentioned

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have an autoscaling group that, using the [Autoscaling Command Line Tools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_BasicSetup.html) doesn't seem to show up unless I explicitly request it. Ie:

```
as-describe-auto-scaling-groups qa-MyAppName
```

Returns the auto scale group:

```
AUTO-SCALING-GROUP  qa-MyAppName  release_1_by_john_smith  us-east-1a  qa-MyAppName  5  10  5
...
```

However the as-describe-auto-scaling-groups command does not show this particular AS group at all:

```
as-describe-auto-scaling-groups
```

Does not return this auto scaling group at all. Other AS groups are shown though.

Why is this AS group not showing in the list of all AS groups?

Comment: Sounds like one for amazon support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many SGs do you have? Unless told otherwise, the as-describe... commands will only return a subset of results (20 by default, IIRC). Perhaps this is number 21?

Comment: About a hundred - this sounds exactly like the problem, thanks! Do you have a link to some docs about this limit?

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't seen it referenced in the AWS docs (although it certainly might be) - I noticed it while looking at the output of 'as-describe-auto-scaling-groups --help'.